Type of diffusion during depolarisation
How would you answer this question? Looks simple, but the emphasis on depolarisation confuses me.
During depolarisation sodium travels across the membrane by

facilitated diffusion;
osmosis;
active transport;
diffusion.

I didn't want to share my ideas so as not to enforce my way of thinking.
I answered 'diffusion' because during depolarisation the ion channels are open and sodium ions freely diffuse inside the neouron. That's why I think the word 'depolarisation' is important. However, the correct answer is apparently 'facilitated diffusion' since the question is about ions entering membrane and they do so through ion channels and hence via facilitated diffusion.
Is my reasoning also correct and does this question allow two interpretations?

Notice the prompt says "sodium travels across the membrane". Can you find a definition in your textbook for "facilitated diffusion"? What does it say?

It says 'Facilitated diffusion is a type of passive transport that uses specialized proteins, such as channel proteins and carrier proteins, to help molecules move across a cell membrane.' I understand that per definition the answer should be 'facilitated diffusion'. I'm just curious as to why the question mentions depolarisation at all.

When do the channels that facilitate movement of sodium across the membrane open?

They open when a membrane potential reaches a value of -55mV.

It's not quite as on/off or binary as a precise voltage "-55 mV"; the voltage-gated sodium channels have a higher probability of being open as the cell depolarizes; that is, as the voltage changes from rest (which, for a typical neuron might be around -75 to -60 mV) towards 0 mV.

From what I've read and seen, the voltage continues to change towards 0 mV only when ions are already going through the channel, not when they approach the channel, hence the confusion with the 'during depolarisation' in the question. Why should it be in the question if it could be substituted by 'Sodium ions enter the neuron membrane by..?'

"not when they approach the channel" doesn't make any sense - ions are always all around the channel, inside and out. They move through only when it's open. Sodium ions also move across the membrane in other ways, for example, the reason there is a lower concentration of sodium ions inside cells compared to outside in the first place is because of the sodium/potassium ion pump, which is a form of Active Transport. Your instructor/textbook writes "during depolarization" in there so you think about sodium channels moving through voltage- or ligand-gated ion channels.

Thank you every much for your time and expertise. Would it be correct to say that sodium ions travel through the channel via simple diffusion?

No, I would not say that. Simple diffusion would imply a channel isn't involved.

This multiple choice question is basically testing whether you understand your textbook's definitions of terms like "facilitated diffusion", and also that you understand that membranes influence how molecules/ions move, and that the mechanisms of movement across membranes depend on what exactly is moving. This is a central concept in biology necessary to understand how life works, because so much of life involves controlling and influencing what does and doesn't cross membranes.
As you mention in a comment:

Facilitated diffusion is a type of passive transport that uses specialized proteins, such as channel proteins and carrier proteins

You also mention:

during depolarisation the ion channels are open

The question prompt is (emphasis added):

During depolarisation sodium travels across the membrane by

The question is asking specifically about ions traveling across the membrane, you know that they move through ion channels in the membrane because you specifically mentioned ion channels, so the answer is clearly facilitated diffusion because it "uses specialized proteins, such as channel proteins". Plain "diffusion" would be used to describe something that moves across the membrane without needing to move through "specialized proteins, such as channel proteins and carrier proteins".

'Plain "diffusion" would be used to describe something that moves across the membrane without needing to move through "specialized proteins, such as channel proteins and carrier proteins".' This actually helps understanding the answer. Thank you very much.
